# Java getting certain value from a hashmap

Tags: java, string, hashmap, integer

code

```
   HashMap <String, Integer> polllist = new HashMap<>();
   public boolean onCommand(CommandSender s, Command Cmd, String label, String[] args)
   {

   }
```

This is where I add the Integer I am searching for to the hashmap

```
    String combine = args[1] + " " + args[2] + " " + args[3] + " " + msg;
    int pn = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
    int pollnumber = pn;
    polllist.put(combine, pollnumber);
```

So I made a HashMap containing a String and an Integer. I tried doing this.

```
    if(polllist.containsValue(args[1]))
    {

    }
```

This does not seem to work, I put an else statement and that always triggers when I know I put a value in the hashmap that equals args[1]. I am trying to find the integer value but it does not seem to work. How would I also get the string value.

Comment: What is your hashmap declaration statement ?

Comment: HashMap <String, Integer> polllist = new HashMap<>();

Comment: You need to provide all relevant details: show the code where you declare the hashmap, where you put a value in it, and show how you run the program and what you pass as `args[1]`. And put it in the question (there is an "edit" button), the comments are not meant for things that are part of your question.

Comment: Assuming `args` is the `main` method's single parameter of type `String[]`, then obviously the `HashMap` with a value type of `Integer` will not contain a value of type `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(polllist.containsValue(Integer.valueOf(args[1])))
```

You converted from `String` to `int` before setting the value so you have to do the same when looking it up.

Also, this is a very backward way to use HashMap.  HashMap performs best when most of the lookups happen on the keys not the values.  You might consider just switching them, as in: `HashMap<Integer, String>`.  But that would require your Integers to be unique.

Answer (score -1):

Your String is the key. Hence you should use:

```
 for (String key : polllist.keySet()) { 
     if(polllist.get(key).equals(yourInteger) ) 
         { 
           //do something 
         } 
  }
```

Comment: Loop through the entire hashmaps keyset. For every key get it's value. See if that value is the integer you are looking for. <br>

`
for (String key : polllist.keySet()) {
    if(polllist.get(key).equals(yourInteger) )
    {
         //do something
    }
}

`

Comment: This presumes that the integer only exists in pollist once or at least you only care that it exists at least once.

Comment: No not really. You are looping through the entire hashmap. Whenever you encounter the integer, the if statement is true. So you can do whatever you want with every occurrence of the integer in the hashmap.